# Почему такая разница в координатах? Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я давно уже не заходил в юнити и помню что-то про глобальные и локальные координаты. Но я не совсем помню, как это дело фиксится правильно? Скрины иерархии и координат приложил. Все объекты на нулевых координатах, а герой явно нет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![
][5]][5]

Comment: Какое «это дело»? Что мешает просто взять и изменить координаты Hero на нужные?

Comment: Если я введу нужные координаты, он будет очень далеко, вообще в другой части. Хотя другие объекты с 0, 0, 0 координатами на своём месте

Comment: «очень далеко» это в каких конкретно глобальных координатах? Точно не в нулевых?

Comment: Точно не в нулевых, около 300-900 разницы

Comment: Я прикрепил ещё два скриншота. Там показано, насколько далеко всё. Персонаж на нулевых координатах и фон на нулевых координатах

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена путём удаления Object Hero. Создал заново пустой объект, прикрепил к нему Sprite формы Square.